# Will Model::updateOrCreate() update a soft-deleted model if the criteria matches?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Let's say I have a model that was soft-deleted and have the following scenario:

```php
// EXISTING soft-deleted Model's properties
$model = [
    'id'         => 50,
    'app_id'     => 132435,
    'name'       => 'Joe Original',
    'deleted_at' => '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
];

// Some new properties
$properties = [
    'app_id'     => 132435,
    'name'       => 'Joe Updated',
];

Model::updateOrCreate(
    ['app_id' => $properties['app_id']],
    $properties
);
```

Is `Joe Original` now `Joe Updated`?

***OR*** is there a deleted record and a new `Joe Updated` record?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**updateOrCreate** will look for model with **deleted_at** equal to **NULL** so it won't find a soft-deleted model. However, because it won't find it will try to create a new one resulting in duplicates, which is probably not what you need.

BTW, you have an error in your code. **Model::updateOrCreate** takes array as first argument.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code. Also, I tried `Model::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate()` but got an exception since it tried to use the query builder instead of the eloquent model.

Comment: It's normal that you're getting an exception cause that's exactly what you're doing - calling updateOrCreate() on a Builder that is returned from withTrashed(). You're trying to misuse the soft deleting trait. It's not designed as a tool to hide records. Regardless whether a model is deleted or soft-deleted you should treat it the same way - there is no such record, so you do not update it. The only operation that you should be able to do is to restore a soft-deleted model. If you really want to update it you can use DB facade.

Comment: I'm actually getting contacts from another external database and saving them, and then pushing them up to hubspot. The database I'm getting them from has bad emails and duplicates. I'm soft deleting all records with bad emails, but when I re-sync I want to update records that have may have fixed their emails and restore them, instead of adding a new record, since they aren't actually new. I have since just added a new method `updateOrCreateWithTrashed`... maybe I should call it `updateOrCreateAndRestoreIfFixed` :P

Comment: Just a note here - in 5.5 at least, `Model::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate()` is valid and works as expected, with the exception that the record is not restored. I couldn't chain the `restore()` method either, so had to check if the returned model was `trashed()` then call `restore()`.

Comment: `Model::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate()` works in L5.4 [tested]

Answer (score 28):

```
$variable = YourModel::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate(
    ['whereAttributes' => $attributes1, 'anotherWhereAttributes' => $attributes2],
    [
        'createAttributes' => $attributes1,
        'createAttributes' => $attributes2,
        'createAttributes' => $attributes3,
        'deleted_at' => null,
    ]
);
```

create a new OR update an exsiting that was soft deleted AND reset the softDelete to NULL

Comment: Nice solution, just remember to add 'deleted_at' to the fillable property of the model! ;)

Comment: Thank you, @Nem, I'd forgotten that step.

Answer (score 5):

```
Model::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate([
   'foo' => $foo,
   'bar' => $bar
], [
   'baz' => $baz,       
   'deleted_at' => NULL     
]);
```

Works as expected (Laravel 5.7) - updates an existing record and "undeletes" it.

Comment: Model remains deleted in Laravel 5.8. It's possible to undelete by `Model::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate(['foo' => $foo], ['baz' => $baz])->restore()`

Answer (score 3):

```
RoleUser::onlyTrashed()->updateOrCreate(
            [
                'role_id' => $roleId,
                'user_id' => $user->id
            ],
            [
                'deleted_at' =>  NULL,
                'updated_at' => new \DateTime()
            ])->restore();
```

Like this you create a new OR update an exsiting that was soft deleted AND reset the softDelete to NULL

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by adding **withTrashed** so that it will include ***soft-deleted*** items when it tries to update or create. Make sure ***deleted_at*** is in the ***fillable array*** of your model.

```
$model = UserRole::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate([
            'creator_id' => $creator->id,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'role_id' => $role->id,
        ],[
            'deleted_at' => NULL
        ])->fresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution by @mathieu-dierckxwith Laravel 5.3 and MySql
If the model to update has no changes (i.e. you are trying to update with the same old values) the `updateOrCreate` method returns null and the `restore()` gives a `Illegal offset type in isset or empty`

Answer (score -1):

try this logic..

```
foreach ($harga as $key => $value) {
    $flight = salesprice::updateOrCreate(
        ['customerID' => $value['customerID'],'productID' => $value['productID'], 'productCode' => $value['productCode']],
        ['price' => $value['price']]
        );
}
```

it work for me